# Key keeps pressing many times

Tags: java, youtube

I am trying to create a program that will:

- Take live chat messages from a livestream
- If the live chat message is a certain control, press and hold that key for two seconds
- Take note of that live chat ID and do not press the key again.

Here is what I have so far. When I run the program and enter a value in the chat box, it presses the key infinitely and does not stop, freezing the computer.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

class Game {
    String[] rawCommands = { "up", "down", "left", "right", "start", "select", "a", "b", "x", "y", "l", "r" };
    int[] transCommands = { KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_B, KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.VK_E, KeyEvent.VK_F,
            KeyEvent.VK_G, KeyEvent.VK_H, KeyEvent.VK_I, KeyEvent.VK_J, KeyEvent.VK_K, KeyEvent.VK_L };
    ArrayList<String> seen = new ArrayList<String>();

    void main() {
        while (true) {
            HashMap<Integer, String[]> messages = listChatMessages();

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
                String[] full = messages.get(i);
                String id = full[0];
                String msg = full[1];

                Result r = oneOfManyIgnoreCase(msg, rawCommands);
                if (r.bool) {
                    if (!oneOfManyIgnoreCase(id, seen.toArray(new String[seen.size()])).bool) {
                        int key = transCommands[Arrays.asList(rawCommands).indexOf(r.msg)];
                        keyPress(key);
                        if (seen.size() > 90) {
                            seen.remove(0);
                        }
                        seen.add(id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void deleteChatMessage(String id) {

    }

    HashMap<Integer, String[]> listChatMessages() {
        HashMap<Integer, String[]> messages = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            URL response = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/m"
                    + "essages?liveChatId=EiEKGFVDaUxwMWJTNFpvc2JlaHA5bHppbGNJQRIFL2xpdmU&part=sn"
                    + "ippet&key=AIzaSyAYFLriWHDy8MJZ_zblU-GuovOoqg6L-28&maxResults=200&pageToken=GKf04s3c7tcCILjGoM7c7tcC");
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(response.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("messages.json");
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            fos.close();

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("messages.json"));
            JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONArray jArr = (JSONArray) jObj.get("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < jArr.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject msg = (JSONObject) jArr.get(i);
                JSONObject snippet = (JSONObject) msg.get("snippet");
                JSONObject txtDetails = (JSONObject) snippet.get("textMessageDetails");
                String[] full = new String[2];
                full[1] = (String) txtDetails.get("messageText");
                full[0] = (String) msg.get("id");

                messages.put(i, full);

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return messages;
    }

    void keyPress(int key) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Robot bot = new Robot();
                    bot.setAutoDelay(1);

                    int duration = 3000;
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                        bot.keyPress(key);
                        bot.keyRelease(key);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    Result oneOfManyIgnoreCase(String one, String[] many) {
        Boolean match = false;
        String message = "";
        for (String man : many) {
            if (one.equalsIgnoreCase(man)) {
                match = true;
                message = man;
                break;
            }
        }
        Result r = new Result(match, message);
        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with the Robot object but ```while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                        bot.keyPress(key);
                        bot.keyRelease(key);
                    }``` looks like it just keeps pressing and releasing the key for X seconds rather than holding it for X seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not a good way to handle key presses. Generally if you want to hold down a key programatically, then you should make the key press occur until the time is up and then after the time is complete wait for like 2 milliseconds and then release the key. I don't think that you are giving the keyboard driver enough time to process the release. Additionally. Try only doing the keypress once, or at least as few times as you need. Usually I think that you only have to press it once and release it once the time is complete if I'm not mistaken.

```
while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
    bot.keyPress(key);
    bot.keyRelease(key);
}
```